# Merge ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, merge, concatenation, relation

In model Banner

```
belongs_to :segment
belongs_to :basic_component
has_many :state_banners, dependent: :destroy
has_many :states, through: :state_banners

scope :banner_have_zero_cities, lambda { includes(state_banners: :state_banner_cities).where(state_banner_cities: {state_banner_id: nil}) }
scope :banner_by_state, lambda { |state_id| where("state_banners.state_id = ?", state_id) }
scope :banner_by_city, lambda { |city_id| joins(state_banners: :state_banner_cities).where("state_banner_cities.city_id = ?", city_id) }
```

In controller

```
def scoped_collection
   @banners_cities = Banner.banner_by_city(city_id)
   @banners_states =Banner.banner_by_state(city.state_id).banner_have_zero_cities
   @banners = @banners_cities.concat(@banners_states)
   return @banners.joins(:basic_component)
 end
```

@banners_states.size
=> 1

@banners_cities.size
=> 2

@banners_states.merge(@banners_cities)
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT `banners`.`id` FROM `banners` INNER JOIN `state_banners` ON `state_banners`.`banner_id` = `banners`.`id` INNER JOIN `state_banner_cities` ON `state_banner_cities`.`state_banner_id` = `state_banners`.`id` WHERE (state_banners.state_id = 3) AND `state_banner_cities`.`state_banner_id` IS NULL AND (state_banner_cities.city_id = '260') LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
=> []

I need 3

i try concat

@banners = @banners_cities.concat(@banners_states)
@banners.size => 3

but

@banners.joins(:basic_component).order("basic_component.order asc").size => 2

CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM `banners` INNER JOIN `state_banners` ON `state_banners`.`banner_id` = `banners`.`id` INNER JOIN `state_banner_cities` ON `state_banner_cities`.`state_banner_id` = `state_banners`.`id` INNER JOIN `basic_components` ON `basic_components`.`id` = `banners`.`basic_component_id` WHERE (state_banner_cities.city_id = '260') LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count

:(, help

Answer (score 0):

Your post is kind of hard to follow, but try `.limit(3)` at the end of the query?